# Tangent line to a 3D curve at a given 3D point

Tags: python, 3d, curves

I'm trying to compute tangent line (or tangent vector) at 3D point of a 3D curve. The problem is how to compute the slope according to x,y and z at point ? 
I recall that for a 2D curve, the equation of the tangent line is:

```
tang=(x-x_k)*slope_k+y_k
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on https://math.stackexchange.com/. Here should be only programming questions

Comment: I want to program this to have the tangent at my 3D point on python..

Comment: Do you have the equation of the curve or is it a series of points?

Comment: Yes, I have the coordinates (x,y,z) of all the points of the 3D curve

Answer (score 0):

The slope in 3D can be written as simple different between two 3D points. Here is why: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799783/slope-of-a-line-in-3d-coordinate-system